# I can't seem to understand the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, determinant, quadratics, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The proof said to use the quadratic polynomial:
$$P(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n(a_it - b_i)^2$$
by which we notice that $P(t) \ge 0$
, but then this is the part which I didn't understand where we conclude that for all $t$:
$$P(t) \ge 0$$
so the discriminant should be:
$$ D = (-2\sum_{i=1}^na_i\ b_i)^2\  - \ 4(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2)\ (\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2) \le 0$$
Unfortunately I tried understanding the reasoning of for all $t$ :
$$P(t) \ge 0 \implies D \le 0$$

But I can't seem to get it through my head. I hope someone could explain to me the logic behind this, I'm very interested in understanding it.

Comment: $P$ is a quadratic function. Its graph can touch the $x$ axis at most twice. $P(x)\geq 0\forall x\in \mathbb R$ is not possible if the graph touches the $x$ axis twice for there would be some negative $P(x)$.

Comment: It is “Schwarz” and not “Shwartz” – [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz)

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/dot-cross-products/v/proof-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible approaches.

**Algebraic approach:** Consider a polynomial of degree 2, that is $p=At^2+Bt+C$. It is known (see [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)) that its roots are
$$t_{\pm}=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{D}}{2A},$$
for $D=B^2-4AC$ the discriminant.

Since $P(t)\ge 0$, then $A>0$ and you cannot have two distinct real roots: otherwise it is easy to see that $P(t)<0$ for $t\in(t_-,t_+)$.

It follows that either you have a single double root, that is $t_-=t_+$, hence by the above equation $D=0$, or two complex root, that is $D<0$.

**Geometric approach:** consider the function $P(t)=At^2+Bt+C$, with $A>0$, which is a parabola. We look for the minimum of $P$.
$$P'(t)=2Ax+B=0\iff t_{\min}=-B/2A.$$

It follows that $$P(t_\min)=P(-B/2A)=\frac{-B^2}{4A}+C=\frac{-B^2+4AC}{4A}=\frac{-D}{4A}.$$
Since $A>0$, $$P(t)\ge0\iff P(t_\min)\ge0\iff -D>0,$$ which proves that $P(t)\ge0$ is equivalent to the non-positivity of the discriminant.

Comment: Oh! So A has to be superior to 0 so the curve will turn upwards thus P(t)≥0, and if there was 2 distinct real roots then it implies P(t)<0 for t∈(t−,t+) which doesn't correlate with P(t)≥0. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct